# Default currency not showing per store view

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore, currency

I have setup multistore as follows:

```
Website A

   Store A
   StoreView A Default currency(GBP), Allowed currencies (EURO) + (GBP)

   Store B
   Storeview B Default currency(EURO), Allowed currencies (GBP) + (EURO)
```

The problem is when I switch to StoreView B the default currency is still showing (GBP) even though I have set the default currency as (Euro).

Has anyone else had this problem and been able to fix it? Please let me know as I am banging my head off of the desk...

Comment: Make sure you cleared Magento cache, browser cache, cookies and reindexed your db.

Comment: @Tim Have done, when I change the store view I expect the currency to change to the default currency of Euro but Nah not happening...

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? If so please mark as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @philwinkle Credit to Inchoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inchoo help me to solve it...
[link]http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/